# How to retrieve radio stream URLs?

Tags: internet-radio

My question is simple but I still haven't found yet...

I'm looking for a reliable source (and a structured one, like XML, RSS, ...) to dynamically get a list of digital radios and their stream URL (preferably for french radios).
My goal is to know these informations at a moment and to be able to refresh these informations if asked by the user.

What I found most relevant is that website :
http://fluxradios.blogspot.fr/p/flux...francaise.html
But such a website could be stopped anytime and the parsing seems to be difficult.

If someone has an idea...

Comment: Please narrow down the scope of your question a bit more. Are we talking digital radio (for which you would need a list of URLs) or analogue radio (for which you would need a list of frequencies)? For which region?

Comment: That's for digital radios and I'm looking for french radios. I edited my question with these precisions.

Answer (score 0):

I use [listenlive.eu](http://www.listenlive.eu/), for Europe based radios. I also use [radiosenlaweb.com](http://www.radiosenlaweb.com/) which is a worldwide list, it has some french ones, but has mostly Latin / South American radios

Comment: Thanks a lot, listenlive.eu is nice. There's still a parser to implement, but this source seems reliable to me.

Comment: However, I let this topic unclosed, just in case someone knows the same in XML or other structured flow.